# When using ctypes in Python, why must CDLL be called in capital letters?

Tags: python, import, ctypes, capitalization, capitalize

I'm trying to load some proprietary DLLs of a piece of hardware I want to control via a Python script. For this, I'm using the `CDLL` module from the `ctypes` package. I encountered this weird issue that for calling `CDLL`, it must be capitalized or else the function call does not work.

Doing the following throws an error:

```
from ctypes import CDLL

mcldll = cdll(r'C:\Program Files\Mad City Labs\NanoDrive\Madlib.dll')    # using lower case


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-4ef065672c09> in <module>
      1 from ctypes import CDLL
      2 
----> 3 mcldll = cdll(r'C:\Program Files\Mad City Labs\NanoDrive\Madlib.dll')

TypeError: 'LibraryLoader' object is not callable
```

But doing this works fine:

```
from ctypes import CDLL

mcldll = CDLL(r'C:\Program Files\Mad City Labs\NanoDrive\Madlib.dll')    # using upper case
```

This is the first time I've encountered an issue with case sensitivity when importing or calling modules in Python. What causes this behavior?

Comment: All of Python is case sensitive.

Comment: If you haven't encountered this before, it's because you never tried. Python has always been case-sensitive for identifiers. Most packages use lowercase functions and module names. Class names, including type classes, are normally PascalCase. Some, like this and uuid.UUID, are all-caps acronyms.

Comment: "I encountered this weird issue that for calling CDLL, it must be capitalized or else the function call does not work." In your own words, why do you think this is "weird"? Have you ever seen it work differently for any other call? Can you show an example?

Comment: Hi, see my question below William's answer

Answer (score 1):

All of Python is case-sensitive. What it seems like you're noticing is that it's unusual for python classes or functions to be in all caps.

Per Python PEP guidelines (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) "Class names should normally use the CapWords convention."

In the source code for ctypes, we can see that CDLL is just a class definition

```py
#line 318 of ctypes/__init__.py
class CDLL(object):
    """An instance of this class represents a loaded dll/shared
    library, exporting functions using the standard C calling
    convention (named 'cdecl' on Windows).
```

So perhaps it seems unusual. I guess the question is how to properly CapWords the word "C DLL". So they just happened to choose "CDLL".

Also, CDLL is a class name, not a module name (which would be all lowercase https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names)

**Edit:** In response to comment below, there does seem to be an all lowercase object `cdll` within ctypes. I am not an expert with ctypes, but it appears to be a different method of loading libraries.

I am not entirely sure of the API differences, but the lowercase `cdll` is intended to be used with the following syntax:

```py
from ctypes import cdll # lowercase
cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")
```

More info at the full docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html)

Comment: That's the thing. I can do both `from ctypes import cdll` and `from ctypes import CDLL`. Here, the import does not seem to be case-sensitive. It only seems to create a problem when **calling** the function/module/class. Why is it that I can import both `cdll` and `CDLL`, while I can only call `CDLL` but **not** `cdll` (even though I just imported it)?

Comment: @joannajanssen see my edit above. Lowercase `cdll` is an instance of the `LoadLibrary` class. It's defined on line 461 of `ctypes/__init__.py` as `cdll=LibraryLoader(CDLL)`. Not sure the importance of that object, you'll have to read more into the recommended usage of the various ctypes interfaces.